# SQL - Inserting the image works, while Updating it does not

Tags: sql, image, ms-access, datagridview

I'm saving my image into my Access database as a byte array, which works. This is the insert code, which is functional:

```
imenikTableAdapter.Insert(
                txtName.Text,
                txtSurname.Text,
                txtPhone.Text,
                txtEmail.Text,
                (picFileName == "") ? null : File.ReadAllBytes(picFileName));
```

The problem occurs when I try to update the record.To debug the problem, I have tried to update the record with the **SAME** input like this: *(Edit: I'm reading the data from the selected row in the DataGridView - this can be ignored as the data is identical to the data used in the INSERT command)*

```
txtName.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
txtSurname.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
txtPhone.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
txtEmail.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
byte[] imageBuffer = row.Cells[5].Value as byte[];

imenikTableAdapter.UpdateQuery(txtName.Text,
      txtSurname.Text,
      txtPhone.Text,
      txtEmail.Text,
      imageBuffer,
      id);
```

And even though this command executes with no problem. When i update the DataGridView, this error pops up:

[image: DataGridView error]
Error.

The only workaround for me right now is deleting the entry and inserting it again, Instead of updating it. (Update works fine when Image is NULL)

So, my question is: why does the INSERT command works, while UPDATE does not, using the SAME byte array for the image?

Comment: Aren't you using two different methods for reading in the images?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean... the image is stored as the same byte array in both the insert and update commands. I don't see how reading the data has anything to do with this issue as DataGridView does the reading itself and not me.

Comment: If you meant how I got the image data... sure - I used different methods, but I already emphasized that the byte arrays are THE SAME. Checked them while debugging.